# pymssql multi insert single commit

Tags: python, sql, t-sql, transactions, pymssql

I am trying to make multiple insertions into the database, with a rollback occuring unless all insertions complete successfully. I can do this easily in TSQL by wrapping the entire block like so:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
    --INSERTIONS GO HERE
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    SELECT Error = 1
END CATCH
```

Now if I try to replicate this behaviour in python using PYMSSQL I try the following:

```
sql=""" SOME SQL CODE HERE """

try:
    cursor = DB.execute(sql)
except:
    DB.rollback()
    print('Fail')
    return False

sql=""" SOME DIFFERENT SQL CODE HERE """

try:
    cursor = DB.execute(sql)
except:
    DB.rollback()
    print('Fail')
    return False

DB.commit()
print('Success')
return True
```

This results in none of the transactions being committed, with no changes seen in the DB. Also if I try to commit after a single insertion using this same method, the insertion is made in the DB, but due to some complex parent child dependencies, the task requires that either all of the insertions are made, or none at all.

I should also mention that a persistent DB connection is kept open using a singleton, which simply overrides the regular connection methods, but causes only a single connection to be allowed open through:

```
def __init__(self, connid='one'):
     self.ensure_conn(connid)

 def ensure_conn(self, connid='one'):
     conn = getattr(self.connection_stack, connid, None)
     if conn is None:
         conn = pymssql.connect(
             self.server, self.user, self.password, self.database)
         self.connection_stack[connid] = conn

 def conn(self, connid='one'):
     self.ensure_conn(connid)
     if connid in self.connection_stack:
         return self.connection_stack[connid]
     else:
         return None
```

I have tried to find examples of this online but the problem seems to be somewhat unique, so any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to leverage stored procedures in TSQL and use pymssql's rpc capabilities. This requires EXEC permissions at the SQL account level, but can be limited to set stored procs for safety  concerns.

By doing this it allows you to leverage the transactional behaviour for multi-inserts on different tables.

```
cursor.callproc(name, args)
```